# How to have ant, ignore (some) drawables directory

Tags: android, ant

I have the following scenario: On my build tree I have, under res/ some drawables directories for higher definition devices that I don't always want to pack when I build my app for lower res devices. It seems that ant will put on the apk all that it finds under res. 
Is there a way that I can selectively tell ant 'ignore my xhdpi resources' ?

Comment: I'm curious, could you please describe the use case in which you are sure your app is only deployed to low res devices??

Comment: @avalancha Because we build the devices where the application is deployed. The applications are not deployed on any other devices.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @user1236327 consisting of using ant is just fine.
I'd like to suggest another approach using Android libraries.

Use several Android libraries, one per resolution.
So your projects could be structured the following way:

- 1: Android library for highres drawables
- 2: Android library for lowres drawables
- 3: Android library for main source code and default drawables
- 4: Android project for highres phones

  - Includes libraries 1 and 3
- 5: Android project for lowres phones

  - Includes libraries 2 and 3

*Of course, note that it is generally recommended to have one single build containing all resolutions drawables.*

Answer (score 0):

I have almost the same problem except I copy different images into the res folder depending on which build I am doing.  In my build.xml I just copy the images over from a separate directory into the resource out folder:

```
<target name="banner_copy">
    <copy file="${my_source_banner_dir}/my_banner_file.png" tofile="${out.res.absolute.dir}/drawable-land-hdpi/my_banner_file.png" overwrite="true"></copy>
</target>
```

You can use the copy ant task to adjust what you need.  You can just copy in the files when you are doing your high resolution builds into your hdpi or whatever res folder you are using for higher resolution images.  One thing you will have to be aware of is to make sure there is a file in one of your res folders to make sure when you are developing eclipse can find the R.drawable. file and creates the generated ID in R.java.  Otherwise it will complain.

Comment: Sounds like a very nice idea. I still need to get my head around the ant tasks. I presume this would be a pre-compile task, on which the build job would depend upon, right?

Comment: Yes.  I put this as the first task in the "depends" to be completed in the target -precompile in the android build scripts .  Just be aware that Android likes to change the build scripts when they update the tools so you may need to copy in the new build.xml and add all your custom code back in when you update your android tools.  I'm about to start looking into gradle as that is the way android is headed.